# try... except... returns an exception if a record isn't found

Tags: python, django

```
class Model1(models.Model):

    def method1(self):
        try:
            x = self.someotherclass_set.get(....)
        except self.DoesNotExist:
            return None 

        return x
```

And then a filter:

```
@register.filter
def filter1(arg1):
    x = var1. method1()
    if x:
        return x.value
    else:
        return 'Nothing'
```

And a view:

```
some data: {{ item|filter1 }}
```

And yet the yellow screen and the error `DoesNotExist` is being throw. How can I get rid of it? I just want to show "Nothing" if there's no record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first) method instead of the `try`/`except` block:

```
def method1(self):
    return self.someotherclass_set.filter(....).first()
```

BTW, you can also simplify the template filter:

```
@register.filter
def filter1(arg1):
    x = arg1.method1()
    return x.value if x else 'Nothing'
```

**UPDATE**: If you really want to use exceptions then change the exception to valid one:

```
except Model1.DoesNotExist:
```

Comment: For some reason it didn't work for me in Django 1.8, not it seems it's working.

Comment: It perfectly works in 1.8.  Show the real code, please.

Comment: I need not just `return arg1.method1()` I need `return arg1.method1().value` and that doesn't work ----> `return arg1.method1().value or 'Nothing'`

Comment: NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: `UPDATE: If you really want to use exceptions then change the exception to valid one:` **except Model1.DoesNotExist** - isn't my code the same?

Comment: I changed the filter code.  And not, your code is not the same.  You use `self` which is a instance of a class but not the class itself.